# Existence of closest point projection to embedded submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I am currently trying to understand closest point projections to a given embedded submanifold $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. In Lee's "Smooth manifolds" I read about the existence of tubular neighborhoods. So far, so good.
However, I now stumbled over the following statement multiple times: Each point $u$ of a tubular neigborhood $U$ posseses a unique closest point $m$ in $M$.

I understand that if I there is a closest point $m$ to $u$, then $u-m$ has to be in $N_mM$, therefore the closest point has to be unique. However, what I do not see is why a closest point must exist without further assumptions on the submanifold like being closed or compact. Why is this the case? Probably, there is a very easy argument I am missing, as I cannot see anyone talk about my issue...

Comment: First, the point $m$ need not be unique if you make the tubular neighborhood too big. Second, look carefully at the definition of tubular neighborhood; if there is no closest point $m$, will your $u$ actually be in the tubular neighborhood? Do you have some examples at hand?

Comment: Your second comment is exactly my problem, where I do not have a clear argument: Why is it not possible that there is a point $u\in U\setminus M$ in my tubular neighborhood, for which there exists a sequence of points $(x_n)\subset M$ with $\|x_n-m\|\to 0$. If $M$ would be closed or even compact, this is clear, as the limit of $(x_n)$ would have to be in $M$. But without such an assumption, I have no clear argument here...

Comment: So if there’s a limit point of $M$ that’s deleted, the normal space at that point is also deleted, so where does your troublesome $u$ live?

Comment: Probably you want to argue that such a point cannot be part of the tubular neighborhood? However, I am afraid, I still do not get your argument. I cannot write down rigorously, why it should not be possible to write a limit point $u$ as $u=m+n$ with any $m\in M$ and a $n\in N_mM$ with $|n|<\rho(m)$ where $\rho$ is the fct defining the tubular neighborhood.